# HTML Tab auto submit page

Tags: javascript, html

I take this simple code from https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_tabs.asp

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
        var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
        tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
        for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
            tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
        for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
            tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
        }
        document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
        evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
    }
```

```css
    body {font-family: Arial;}
    
    /* Style the tab */
    .tab {
        overflow: hidden;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
    }
    
    /* Style the buttons inside the tab */
    .tab button {
        background-color: inherit;
        float: left;
        border: none;
        outline: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        transition: 0.3s;
        font-size: 17px;
    }
    
    /* Change background color of buttons on hover */
    .tab button:hover {
        background-color: #ddd;
    }
    
    /* Create an active/current tablink class */
    .tab button.active {
        background-color: #ccc;
    }
    
    /* Style the tab content */
    .tabcontent {
        display: none;
        padding: 6px 12px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        border-top: none;
    }
```

```html
    
    <p>Click on the buttons inside the tabbed menu:</p>
    
    <div class="tab">
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">London</button>
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
    </div>
    
    <div id="London" class="tabcontent">
      <h3>London</h3>
      <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
    </div>
    
    <div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
      <h3>Paris</h3>
      <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
    </div>
    
    <div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
      <h3>Tokyo</h3>
      <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
    </div>
    

    <form action="action_page.php" method="get"> 
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

I just added the form
But If I tried to navigate across the tab, it's immediately submit the form, without pressing `submit` button.

Most likely it something in JavaScript but I can't figure out what need to be modified.

What is wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Yes of course, I closed form elemet.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is workin you just in `onclick` you called a method didn't initiated yet.

You should make `<script></script>` and define the function before using it.

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
        var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
        tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
        for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
            tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
        for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
            tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
        }
        document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
        evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
    }
```

```css
    body {font-family: Arial;}
    
    /* Style the tab */
    .tab {
        overflow: hidden;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
    }
    
    /* Style the buttons inside the tab */
    .tab button {
        background-color: inherit;
        float: left;
        border: none;
        outline: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        transition: 0.3s;
        font-size: 17px;
    }
    
    /* Change background color of buttons on hover */
    .tab button:hover {
        background-color: #ddd;
    }
    
    /* Create an active/current tablink class */
    .tab button.active {
        background-color: #ccc;
    }
    
    /* Style the tab content */
    .tabcontent {
        display: none;
        padding: 6px 12px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        border-top: none;
    }
```

```html
    
    <p>Click on the buttons inside the tabbed menu:</p>
    
    <div class="tab">
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">London</button>
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
    </div>
    
    <div id="London" class="tabcontent">
      <h3>London</h3>
      <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
    </div>
    
    <div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
      <h3>Paris</h3>
      <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
    </div>
    
    <div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
      <h3>Tokyo</h3>
      <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
    </div>
    

    <form action="action_page.php" method="get"> 
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

Comment: @Green_Crocodile don't forget to mark as solution to close the question